# MySQL, Дата - значение по умолчанию

Tags: mysql, sql

В MySQL необходимо создать таблицу, чтобы в поле `date` по умолчанию писались текущие Год и месяц.
У меня родилось вот ЭТО:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reestrs (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  reestr_id INT NOT NULL,
  date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m')
)
```

Comment: В версии 8+ - легко. В версии 5+ - только триггерной логикой. Но есть подвох - поле типа DATE не умеет хранить неполную дату. Так что или храните с номером дня (скажем, первое число всем), или делайте варчар.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, очень помогли)